# Offline install of setuptools

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, offline, pypi

I am trying to install python packages offline. I have downloaded from PYPI and when I am trying to install, I am getting an error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'". So I have downloaded "setuptools" from PYPI and tried to install, but the setup.py in setuptools already has "import setuptools". So, error again. Please help with this issue.

How do I install setup tools offline ?

Thankyou

Answer (score -1):

download wheel file .whl file :[like to the wheel file](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f7/30/f963996d7efea5a336455a3c727711469280c318e2711e295007dea04d7e/setuptools-52.0.0-py3-none-any.whl).
then open terminal(as admin) and go to the directory which your whl file exists.
type : `pip install {name of your setuptools}.whl`
hope it works.:)

Comment: But to install PIP, it is asking for Systemtools again

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways you can do an offline install, either by downloading the .whl file or by downloading the .tar.gz file (source), and then using pip to install it. Please note you'll need python3 and the corresponding pip for the installation to succeed. You can use one of the following commands depending on if it's a .whl or .tar.gz-

```
pip3 install setuptools-52.0.0-py3-none-any.whl

pip3 install setuptools-52.0.0.tar.gz
```

Comment: But to install PIP, it is asking for Systemtools again

Comment: Strange! I used "apt-get install python3-pip" command (since I'm using Ubuntu) to install pip, and I didn't face any such issue.

Comment: Ya, but It needs internet to install. I am installing offline.